# Variational problem with constraint involving a functional

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I am trying to solve a variational problem which involves finding the function $g(x)$ subject to the BCs $g(0) = 0, g(1) =1$, is bounded and monotonic, and which minimises the functional:

$\mathcal{S}[f[g(x)]] = \int_0^1 f[g(x)] dx$

and the constraint, or the relationship between $f$ and $g$ is given by the ODE on $[0,1]$:

$f''(x) = (\lambda + g(x)) f(x)$
with BCs: $f(0) = f(1) = 0$

Since this ODE does not have a closed-form solution for general $g(x)$, I don't know how to express the variation in $f$ caused by a variation in $g$: could someone point me to references dealing with these types of constraints or share any ideas? I have tried googling things like "Lagrangian involving functional" or "constraint involving functional", etc. but to no avail.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions for the ODE?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I've added them to the question, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Presuming you don't want the solution $f(x) = 0$, this is an eigenvalue problem, meaning our choice of $\omega$ will also depend on our choice of $g$. We also need to know which eigenvalue we're looking at. The ground state? Something else?

Comment: @eyeballfrog let's say we're looking at the ground state - how can I express the variation $\delta f$, given $\delta g$, since I don't know what $g$ is to begin with (we are trying to optimize it), and the Schrodinger equation rarely has a closed form solution anyway? Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious here

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Should that be $-\omega^2$ so that when $g(x) = 0$ the solutions are sinusoidal?

Comment: OK, fine, one other other thing. Are there any constraints on $g$, such as monotonicity, boundedness, continuity, smoothness, normalizability, etc, or can it be any function $[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog eventually, I would like to constrain it to be monotonic and bounded, subject to BCs $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. But since I can't even formulate the problem for the most general case, I left this out of the question. :)

Comment: Generality is not always a good thing, as it can take you from "here's how to solve this" to "no solution in general". Best to include the details when available.

Comment: @eyeballfrog right. I suppose because I am most interested in how to express the derivatives of $f$, I didn't consider those details to be important, but I have now included them!

Comment: Does $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried solving your problem using the variational principle and the [fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations). As the development is quite long, I wrote it on a tablet and put it in a Google Drive folder:

[Complete development on personal Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KIimO95JJAA3DHPICOEmQKrzzsZHirQE/view?usp=share_link)

Here is a summary:

I call your functional $\mathcal{S[f[g(x)]]}$ $I[f, g]$. I define the functionnal $\tilde I [\epsilon, \eta ]$ such as, for all admissible variations $u, v$ and for all real $\epsilon, \eta$:

$$
\left.\frac{\partial I[f + \eta v, g + \epsilon u]}{\partial \epsilon}\right|_{\epsilon = 0} = 0
$$

I don't consider the partial derivative with respect to $\eta$ whch leads to a dead end.

Using integration by parts, I find:

$$\frac{\partial \tilde I [\epsilon, \eta]}{\partial \epsilon} = \left[u f' \right]_b^a - \int_0^1 u .u'.f''(g+\epsilon u) \ dx$$

Using the fundamental lemma and your link between $f$ and $g$, I deduce:

$$u'(g(x) + \lambda)f(x) = 0$$

So if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (note that you did not write the nature of $\lambda$ at the time I write this answer), the only acceptable solutions would be the trivial ones with $f(x) = 0$ because of your BCs.

Sorry for the late answer, I hope it helped. If I did a mistake I would be glad to know it and correct it.